# How to make a link button visible after another button has been clicked in asp.net(vb) in button_click()

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, linkbutton

How to make a  link button visible after another button has been clicked in asp.net(vb) in  button_click()

it says error as "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

i've done this in my code

Protected Sub InsertButton_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

```
    Dim receipt As LinkButton = FormView1.FindControl("LinkButton1")

   ' receipt.Enabled = "true"
   ' receipt.EnableTheming = "true"
   ' receipt.EnableViewState = "true"
    receipt.Visible = "true"
```

End Sub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the form name like this:

```
Dim receipt As LinkButton = FindControl("LinkButton1")
If (Not receipt Is Nothing)
   ' receipt.Enabled = "true"
   ' receipt.EnableTheming = "true"
   ' receipt.EnableViewState = "true"
    receipt.Visible = "true"
End if
```

Comment: sorry mate forgot it,, had to implement that first

Answer (score 0):

Or like this...

```
    LinkButton1.Visible = "true"
```